# Visual Studio for Mac 2019: Unable to copy file "/.file" to "bin/roslyn/.file". Access to the path "/.file" is denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET project using Visual Studio for Mac, the 2019 edition. It's an older project and I've been advised that the 2019 edition of VS is what should work.

When I try to build the project, I get this error: `Unable to copy file "/.file" to "bin/roslyn/.file". Access to the path "/.file" is denied.`. There are similar questions on StackOverflow, but in those questions most users have been denied access to the file destination (`bin/roslyn`), not the file itself (`/.file`). I'm not even able to find a `/.file` in my project which is confusing.

Here are some things I've tried:

- checking the file permissions for every folder in the project (I have read/write access)
- cleaning and rebuilding the project (clean is successful, rebuild yields same error)
- deleting the roslyn folder and rebuilding
- closing all instances of Visual Studio and rebuilding (fails)

Thank you for any help

Comment: try right click, and launch vs as administrator.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it's macOS, that isn't an option sadly.